# Configuring HTTP(S) proxy for specific user on Kali

Tags: kali-linux, chrome, proxy

This question deals with Kali Linux.

I need to open a Chrome browser for a specific user such that for this user, the traffic from Chrome will go through a local HTTP(S) proxy.

Currently, I open the browser from a Python code that runs the command:

```
gksu -wu USERNAME google-chrome
```

I googled a lot, did not find how to do that, and tried without success many solutions for similar questions.

I consider to do one of the following two things, and will be glad to get help in how to do them:

1. Change something in the configurations of the system (e.g., making all the HTTP(S) traffic go through the proxy), such that running the abovementioned command will just work fine.
2. Running additional commands everytime I run the the command.
3. Doing something else.

Please don't offer me to use another browser; I know that in Firefox it is much more simple.

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't you just switch to that user, configure Chrome to use a proxy using the regular method, and then when you execute that command as that user, it'll retain the proxy settings?

Comment: @EightBitTony Chrome takes its proxy configuration from the OS (unlike Firefox for example).

Comment: Then set `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` in the user's profile (which I assume is what Chrome on Linux checks?)

Comment: However, this is Kali, so keep this answer in mind - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: @EightBitTony Of course I tried to set environment variables. I tried to change conf files. It just did not work . (I'm not noob)

Comment: Well, given we know nothing about you - maybe you should describe what you *have* tried in your question so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution. I'm writing it here to help other people who might encounter the same problem.

Although this is not a pure terminal solution, I configured the proxy for the specific user by opening the network window with the same user:

```
gksu -wu USERNAME gnome-control-center network
```

Then I configured the proxy as I wanted. It is an acceptable solution for me, because I need to do the non-terminal process only once.